# Errors with angular-cli

Tags: node.js, angular

I have installed NodeJS and try to build the example project from [ng-book2](https://github.com/papapin/Ng-book-2-/blob/master/ng-book2-r49.pdf)

On page 5 I need to run `ng` And there are WARNINGS.

I found solution (Link 2) and try it, but there are ERRORS, so, I changed version: [image: ***(picture 5)***]

But it doesn`t help too. [image: ***(picture 6)***]

Please, help me.

Comment: Link 1: https://github.com/papapin/Ng-book-2-/blob/master/ng-book2-r49.pdf

Comment: Link 2: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1558

Comment: Link 3: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5558

Comment: Pic. 1: http://savepic.ru/14677455.jpg

Comment: Pic. 2: http://savepic.ru/14667215.jpg

Comment: Pic. 3: http://savepic.ru/14668239.jpg

Comment: Pic. 4: http://savepic.ru/14648783.jpg

Comment: Pic. 5: http://savepic.ru/14652879.jpg

Comment: Pic. 6: http://savepic.ru/14640591.jpg